# Why is a strict $p$-ring whose residue ring is a field necessarily local?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a strict $p$-ring. Recall that this means $A$ is $p$-adically separated and complete, $p:A\rightarrow A$ is injective, and $A/pA$ is a perfect $\mathbf{F}_p$-algebra. If $A/pA$ is a field, then $A$ is known to be a discrete valuation ring. The only way I have seen this proved is to use the actual construction of the $p$-Witt ring $W(A/pA)$, and I'm wondering if there is a way to prove this using only the definition of a strict $p$-ring.

In general, a ring $B$ is a discrete valuation ring if and only if it is local, max-adically separated, and its maximal ideal is principal and non-nilpotent (this is basically Proposition 2 in Serre's Local Fields, although in place of the separated hypothesis, he has a Noetherian hypothesis). If $A$ is a strict $p$-ring with $A/pA$ a field, then $pA$ is maximal, and non-nilpotent by definition. Also, $A$ is $p$-adically separated by definition. But I can't think of a simple way to prove that $A$ is local, i.e., that $pA$ is the unique maximal ideal of $A$. I suppose one could work out the universal formulas which define the ring operations on such a ring and use them to characterize the non-units as precisely the elements of $pA$, but I was hoping there might be a way to avoid this.

The reason I expect such a thing might be possible is that Serre claims that "a complete discrete valuation ring, absolutely unramified, with perfect residue field $k$, is nothing other than a strict $p$-ring with residue ring $k$." He doesn't give any argument for why a strict $p$-ring whose residue ring is a field is local. This leads me to believe I'm missing a potentially obvious argument.

I apologize if this question doesn't seemed well-defined. The ring operations on a strict $p$-ring can be derived from the definitions (starting by proving the existence of a multiplicative system of representatives, then getting series expansions, etc.), so, proving locality from this, strictly speaking, is just using the definitions, but I would say there's considerable work involved (or at least considerable messiness). Basically I'm trying to avoid writing down the polynomials that give the ring structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $x\not\in pA$, then there is some $y$ such that $xy\equiv1$(mod $p$). Then $x$ is invertible mod $p^n$ for any $n$ since $(xy)^{p^n}\equiv 1$(mod $p^n$). Thus $x$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

This is old but let me add a slight generalization which will be helpful to people looking at this now.

**Lemma** Let $R$ be a perfect *local* ring then $W(R)$ is a *local* strict $p$-ring.

Note that the topology on $W(R)$ is $p$-adically complete and separated. But that means $p$ is in the Jacobson radical. Indeed, it is enough to show that $1-px$ is invertible for every $x\in W(R)$. This follows because the inverse is the series $\sum_i (px)^i$, which converges $p$-adically. Now note that $W(R)/p=R$ which is local, so there is precisely $1$ maximal ideal containing $p$ in $W(R)$.

Notice that we didn't use $p$-torsion freeness anywhere.

Comment: nice: questions for people outside of this area: why is this given series actually the inverse? I might miss something here. secondly: why does your argument show that all maximal ideals are open? thanks

Comment: For your question 1, this follows because $(1-px)^{-1}=1+(px)+(px)^2+\ldots$ which is the geometric series from calculus. For your second question, note that the ideal generated by $(p)$ is open in $W(R)$. If $J$ is an ideal containing $(p)$ then it is open. Indeed $J=\bigcup_{x\in J}(x+(p))$. From the argument, every maximal ideal contains $(p)$ hence is open.